# Measuring the effect of X on Z, controlling for the association between X and Y. Semipartial correlation?

Tags: correlation, partial-correlation

So, I have 3 variables: X, Y, Z. All three are inter-correlated. X is my IV, and Y and Z are both DVs; indeed, they are quite similar constructs.

I want to know if X predicts Z more than it does Y. I know I can run a Fischer's r-to-z test. Is there any other test I can run?

Furthermore, given that Y and Z are highly correlated, can I look at the correlation between X and residualised Z (controlling for Y) to ascertain the effect of X on Y per se? Or is this a bad interpretation of the semipartial correlation?

Comment: The correct usage of "semipartial correlation" concept would be when there is one DV and 2 IVs. You say you have  1 IV and 2 DVs In this context, what does it mean to obtain residuals from predicting one DV from another DV?

Comment: What would it mean for one thing to be "predicted more than" another thing?

Comment: I share your intuition about this, ttnphns. But if you strip out the causal connotations of IV/DV language, we just have three variables that co-vary with one another. That's what prompted the idea that one might be able to do this just as well in the 1 IV-2 DV case.

whuber, it would mean that some X is a more important factor in determining Z than it is for Y. For example, exercise might be a more important factor in determining BMI than heart rate at rest (even though BMI and HR at rest might be significantly correlated).